# Insert a character before the file or .(extension)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I wanted to insert the prefix before the file extention.

#Sample filename

DOC.doc

#code

```js
let filename = "Doc.doc"
const prefix = Date.now().toString();
filename += prefix;
```

#Desired output (1595214202266 is the prefix.)

```
DOC-1595214202266.doc
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split the fileName on "." and concat the prefix to file and make the string.

```js
const prefix = Date.now().toString();

var fileName = "DOC.doc"

var [name, ext] = fileName.split('.');
console.log(`${name}-${prefix}.${ext}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let filename = "Doc.doc"
    const prefix = Date.now().toString();
    let extensionIndex = filename.indexOf(".");

filename = filename.substr(0,extensionIndex) + "-" +
                        prefix + filename.substr(extensionIndex,filename.length);
    console.log(filename);
```